# My Javascript scroll function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(
  ".header .nav-bar .nav-list .hamburger"
);
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector(".header .nav-bar .nav-list ul");
const menu_item = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".header .nav-bar .nav-list ul li a"
);
const header = document.querySelector(".header .container");

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    var scroll_position = window.scrollY;
    if (scroll_position > 250) {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "#29323c";
    } else {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
});
```

```
<section id="header">
    <div class="header container">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="brand">
                <a href="#hero">
                    <h1>ELITE.</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-list">
                <div class="hamburger"><div class="bar"></div></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#hero" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services" data-after="Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects" data-after="Projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" data-after="Our CEO">Our CEO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I scroll past 250 the background color is not changing from transparent to the expected color in the JS code. How can I make MY JS respond on browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `.header .container` instead of `#header .container`

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(
  ".header .nav-bar .nav-list .hamburger"
);
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector(".header .nav-bar .nav-list ul");
const menu_item = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".header .nav-bar .nav-list ul li a"
);
const header = document.querySelector("#header .container");

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    var scroll_position = window.scrollY;
    if (scroll_position > 250) {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "#29323c";
    } else {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
});
```

```css
#header {
 position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
    <div class="header container">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="brand">
                <a href="#hero">
                    <h1>ELITE.</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-list">
                <div class="hamburger"><div class="bar"></div></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#hero" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services" data-after="Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects" data-after="Projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" data-after="Our CEO">Our CEO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<div style="height:500vh"></div>
```

Comment: Check the updated JS and assist.

Comment: can you explain the div with class style at the bottom?

Comment: It makes the body scrollable

Comment: my body is already scrollable, I have a full website with only that js error. I defined the header as a constant is there need to define again?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Can you try it with my updated js code and give feedback? its not working on my end.

Comment: Sure I can wait a min

Comment: It worked the query selector was .header instead of #header thanks.

Comment: Can you assist me on another code error, also vote my question up if you don't mind.

Comment: If you post it as a question, yes

Comment: People are so negative here the site wont allow me to ask questions?

Comment: when I change my background image in a section an image after in the same section dissapears

Comment: Sorry. I cannot help without any code

Comment: let me share the code

Comment: #about .about {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: o auto;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}
#about .col-left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 360px;
}
#about .col-right {
  width: 100%;
}
#about .col-right h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: yellow;
}
#about .col-right p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}

Comment: #about .col-left {
  position: relative;
}
#about .col-left .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
#about .col-left .img::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -33px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}

Comment: I have shared the css code in two different comments, when I add a background color the #about.co.-left.img:after dissapears

Comment: html code <section id="about">
      <div class="about container">
        <div class="col-left">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="img/lg.jpg" alt="img" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
          <h1 class="section-title">LG</h1>
          <h2>Our CEO </h2>
          <p>
             “We will do it, if we don’t finish it, then
            the people we leave behind will finish it for us”
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

Comment: Are you able to arrange the code in an editor?